# Detect "No Window" selection in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, webrtc, desktop-sharing

In Firefox, if I need to add screen sharing functionality I must add my domain to the **media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains** Firefox property from **about:config**. Otherwise I'll get error:

**"NotAllowedError": "The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context."**

Ok, all is great, after adding of domain user can select window to share. But he can also select **"No Window"** in screen sharing native popup of Firefox. In this case I'll get absolutely the same error as if **media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains** was not touched.

Is there any way to detect "No Window" selection?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @MichaelKork. Firefox no longer needs media.getusermedia.screensharing.allowed_domains for screen sharing, so problem disappeared